# Python: Access class method variable from another file

Tags: python-3.x, class, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 GUI code and it has a `Ui_MainWindow` class and this class has a `setupUI` method. Here is my `gui.py`:

```
import io
import sys
import os
import core as c
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1022, 637)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1022, 637))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1022, 637))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setKerning(False)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setMouseTracking(True)
        MainWindow.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        .
        .
        .
        self.lineEditSiteX = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)

        self.actionCalculate.triggered.connect(c.cal) # Here is where I'm stuck!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the comment above I'm trying to call a function from another file named `core.py` as as follows:

```
import gui

def cal():
    val = gui.Ui_MainWindow().lineEditSiteX.value()
    return val ** (1/val*2)
```

I simply want when someone clicks on `Calculte` the `lineEdit` value will be accessed through the `core.py` file. But it gives me an `attributeError`. How can I do it?

Comment: Why is it necessary for the GUI task to move to another external part of the GUI? It makes no sense.

Comment: I'm trying to explain it using a simple process. I want to do a lot of things to `setupUi` attributes in `core.py` file.

Comment: I suspect that you want to divide your project into: business logic and GUI, but the task of cleaning is part of the GUI and not of business logic. Business logic are generally tasks that if the GUI is eliminated, they still persist, for example if I implement an application that uploads images then there is an internal part that is to upload the image that does not depend on the GUI, and that is the part of the logic of business, and then on that layer I can implement the GUI layer or a CLI layer or any other layer that uses business logic. For me what you are trying to do has a bad design

Comment: I've edited the question dear @eyllanesc, so ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

- Business logic should not depend on the GUI but the GUI should only use business logic.
- PyQt recommends creating a class that inherits from the appropriate widget and using the class generated by Qt Designer (for more information [read here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code)).

Considering the above, the solution is:

**core.py**

```py
def cal(val):
    return val ** (1/val*2)
```

**gui.py**

```py
import io
import sys
import os
import core as c
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        # ... 
        self.lineEditSiteX = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionCalculate.triggered.connect(self.on_actionCalculate)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_actionCalculate(self):
        try:
            val = float(self.lineEditSiteX.text())
        except ValueError:
            print("error")
        finally:
            res = c.cal(val)
            print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc for your answer. But the main concept that I'm looking for is: How to reach class method attributes e.g.`self.lineEditSiteX` or `self.actionCalculate` from another `.py` script. Could you please edit your answer to match that? I have to say I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: @AfshinSalehi mmm, it seems that you have not realized that what you require can not, if you want to modify a property of an object from another external class / function / etc then you must create an object or pass the object, for example in your initial code changes to `self.actionCalculate.triggered.connect(lambda *args, p=self:c.cal(self))` and `def cal(obj):` `val = int(obj.lineEditSiteX.text())` but for me that is a bad design that can bring you more problems in the future so I will not propose it in my answer.